# Total today, total yesterday ... total 7 days ago, total last week, average this month -data awareness in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi

I want an easy way to have a sum of yesterday, the day before and the day before that total 7 columns (past 7 days)

Then i would like average for L7D, Average LM.

I have made a column in my date that indicate what "today" is and then my idea was to have it sum if today, sum if today-1, sum if today-2 but this does not seem to work
)

Yesterday= CALCULATE(SUM('DanvægtLines'[NAV_Qty]);FILTER('DanvægtLines';'DanvægtLines'[Dato_Anden]>=TODAY()-1)

(It take the sum of quanto, then filters if the 2.date on the order is today)

It is only working with ">=" not if i only use "="  ... witch is ok for yesterday, but the if i want to have only 4 days ago i have to filter yesterday, the day before, and 3 days ago... witch make a very very long code line   i dont get why

=(today()-4 wont work)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after about 15 hours of hair pulling it dawned on me that the table I was referring to was in the date+time format, so fixing that I could use `=today()-1`